# How we can use a checkbox as a parameter in report?

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am new in SSRS world. Is it possible to use a check box as parameters? For example, suppose there are 3 parameter in my reports. The 1st one is Site, the 2nd one is  Component and the Third one is Check box (name 'ISComponentIncluded'). If we check the third parameter then the 2nd parameter will be considered, otherwise it will be disabled.

Can anyone help me regarding that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can dynamically hide/show a parameter at run time. The best option would be to change your query to account for whether or not the check box was checked. Something like this perhaps?

```
where
 1 = case when @iscomponentincluded = 1 then 1 when @component = field then 1 else 0 end
```